# Making a Sierpiński triangle by moving a point.

Tags: geometry, triangles, fractals

Let $A,B,$ and $C$ be three distinct fixed points. Let $D$ be a point that moves as follows:

I. Place $D$ anywhere.

II. Choose $A,B,$ or $C$ randomly.

III. Consider the mid-point of the line joining $D$ and the chosen point in step II.

IV. Move $D$ to the mid-point obtained in step III.

Repeat steps (II,III, and IV) large number of times.

You will end with a shape that is similar to the Sierpiński triangle, with the consideration where did you place $A,B,$ and $C$.

Here I have two questions;

> Why does that happen?

and

> If we repeat the number of iterations [steps II, III, IV] infinitely
>   many times, then what is the ratio of the area where $D$ can not be
>   there to the area of $\triangle ABC$? Assuming that $D$ was not
>   initially placed inside $\triangle ABC$.

Any help will be appreciated.